# condition_variable wait_for in C++

Tags: c++, condition-variable, unique-lock

I am working with `condition_variable` on Visual studio 2019. The `condition_variable.wait_for()` function returns `std::cv_status::no_timeout` without any notification.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;
bool called = false;

void printThread()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (std::cv_status::timeout == cv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::seconds(1)))
    {
        std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << "thread exits" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th(printThread);
    th.join();
    std::cout << "program exits" << std::endl;
}
```

I think the code will never exit and keep printing `*`, but it exits after printing some `*`.

Here is the output:

```
********************************************************************thread exits
program exits
```

Why does this happen? Is it the so-called "spurious wakeups"？

Comment: @JHBonarius he has infinitive `while` loop. `wait_for` should always return `std::cv_status::timeout` since notification is not triggered.

Comment: @JHBonarius Are you saying that the condition_variable is taking more than one second to acquire the mutex?

Comment: @JHBonarius and as I point out as `notify_xx` is never called so it has to always timeout.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/a971GW works for me (timeouts). Here also it timeouts: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y2YBuLYegnufDhXF

Comment: @MarekR It doesn't have to timeout. It *can* timeout, but it doesn't have to. His code isn't waiting for anything in particular, so it can wakeup unpredictably.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's a "spurious wakeup". This is explained on [cppreference.com's reference page for `wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for):

> It may also be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the
> reason, lock is reacquired and wait_for() exits.

Translation: there are gremlins in your computer. They get grumpy, occasionally. And if they do get grumpy, `wait_for` returns before the requested timeout expires. And when that happens:

> Return value
>
> 1. std::cv_status::timeout if the relative timeout specified by
>    rel_time expired, std::cv_status::no_timeout otherwise.

And that seems to be exactly what you're seeing. The C++ standard permits a C++ implementation to return from `wait_for` prematurely, for arbitrary reasons, and unless you ***do*** return from `wait_for` when the timeout expires, `no_timeout` is what you get.

You might be wondering why `wait_for` (and several other similar functions) may decide to throw up their hands and return "spuriously". But that would be a different question...

Comment: And this is why the various flavors of `wait()` on a condition variable are always called in a loop that checks for an actual change of some significant variable, and repeats the wait if no change has occurred. Timed waits are not a replacement for an appropriate sleep. Waits are intended to wait for something to happen, and correct code has to check that it actually happened. +1.

Comment: Ok, but how does that explain the behaviour? In his example the while loop only loops if the wait_for returns `timeout` and exitst otherwise. So how come the return values changes from timeout to something else after a while (making the loop exit and the function end)? Timer overflow?

Comment: @JHBonarius His code seems to assume that a condition variable has two states, signaled and unsignaled, and it stops looping if the condition variable is in the signaled state. But condition variables are stateless -- they don't have any state. It's not a timer overflow or anything else. For code like this to work, the programmer has to implement some way of tracking state, and this code doesn't. So its behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't fully understand. Because the check is not made on the state of the cv, but on the return value of a specific variant of `wait_for`, which according to cppref` only has two output possibilities. There must be some state in there, how else would you know of a time out has occurred? And if you cannot trust the return value to be `timeout` at all times after this timeout, how can you build any reliable application on top of it?

Comment: Ok, I'm keeping the previous comment as a reference of where my misconception came from. I don't know why (probably because I've never had to use a cv before) but I completly missed the part of the code where a whole new wait_for is triggered on every loop iteration. I thought the same timeout period was checked every iteration. Now I understand where my misunderstanding came from and I understand what's happening.

Comment: Just to help anyone else: The wait operation has a state, it can timeout or not, but the condition variable itself doesn't have a state. As for how you build something reliable on top of it, you use the return value *only* to determine whether you timed out or not.

Answer (score -1):

As already explained, it is waking up due `spurious wakeup`. Such thing make the function `wait_for` completely useless. The solution is to use the `wait_until` saving the current time before entering the wait loop:

```cpp
int count = 1;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable condition_variable;

void wait() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    count--;

    int timeout = 1000; // 1 second
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> timenow = 
        std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    while(count < 0) {
        std::cv_status status = condition_variable.wait_until(
            lock, 
            timenow + std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1,1000>>(timeout));

        if ( std::cv_status::timeout == status) {
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```